# Update form from an async event (websocket) from other thread (VBNET)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, variables, websocket

I am trying to update a label on my form after I receive a message from an async fired event from another class, and nothing is working so far.

Well, one thing that worked was adding a timer on the main thread that updates the label every 200ms with a public variable from the other class. But there must be an other way.

I tried to use the invoke method, but that didn't work either.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

edit: The function below is called with:

`Await SubscribeToWebsocketEvents(creds)`

**The function:**

```vb
Public Shared Async Function SubscribeToWebsocketEvents(ByVal creds As Credentials) As Task
    Dim socket = New CoinbaseProWebSocket(New WebSocketConfig With {
    .ApiKey = creds.ApiKey,
    .Secret = creds.ApiSecret,
    .Passphrase = creds.ApiPassphrase,
    .SocketUri = "wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com"
})

    WriteLine(">> Connecting websocket...")

    Dim result = Await socket.ConnectAsync()

    If Not result.Success Then Throw New Exception("Connect error.")
    WriteLine(">> Connected.")

    AddHandler socket.RawSocket.Closed, (AddressOf Websocket_Closed)
    AddHandler socket.RawSocket.Error, (AddressOf Websocket_Error)
    AddHandler socket.RawSocket.MessageReceived, (AddressOf Websocket_MessageReceived)

    Dim Subsc = New Subscription

    Subsc.ProductIds.AddRange({"BTC-EUR", "BTC-USD"})
    Subsc.Channels.Add("ticker")
    Subsc.Channels.Add("matches")

    WriteLine(">> Subscribing to events...")
    Await socket.SubscribeAsync(Subsc)
    WriteLine(">> Subscribed.")
End Function
```

**The event:**

```vb
Private Shared Sub Websocket_MessageReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebSocket4Net.MessageReceivedEventArgs)
    WriteLine("Message received.")

    Dim msg = Nothing, hb As HeartbeatEvent = Nothing, tk As TickerEvent = Nothing

    Form1.BitcoinPriceLabel.Text = "Test to see if I can edit the label"

    If WebSocketHelper.TryParse(e.Message, msg) Then
        If CSharpImpl.__Assign(hb, TryCast(msg, HeartbeatEvent)) IsNot Nothing Then
            '     WriteLine($"Sequence: {hb.Sequence}, Last Trade Id: {hb.LastTradeId}")
        End If
        If CSharpImpl.__Assign(tk, TryCast(msg, TickerEvent)) IsNot Nothing Then
            If tk.ProductId = "BTC-EUR" Then
                WriteLine($"Coin: {tk.ProductId}, Last value: {tk.Price}, BestAsk: {tk.BestAsk}")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the default instance of `Form1` on a secondary thread. Default instances are thread-specific so the instance you update is not the instance you have displayed. Read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html) for more information.

The solution is to invoke a method on the UI thread and then the default instance you use will be the same one you displayed. If you are in a class that is not a form or other control, the way to do that is with the `SynchronizationContext` class, e.g.

```vb
Private context As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

'This method is executed on a secondary thread.
Private Sub BackgroundMethod()
    context.Post(AddressOf ForegroundMethod, Nothing)
End Sub

'This method is executed on the UI thread.
Private Sub ForegroundMethod(state As Object)
    'Update the UI here.
End Sub
```

You need to create the instance of that type on the UI thread and then the current context it gets will be that for the UI thread. That context is used to post a delegate to that thread later. The method you create the delegate for must have a single parameter of type `Object`. When you call `Post` pass any data you require to that parameter and then cast as the appropriate type in the posted method. In your case, the method might look like this:

```vb
Private Sub SetForm1BitcoinPriceLabelText(text As Object)
    Form1.BitcoinPriceLabel.Text = text
End Sub
```

and you might call it like this:

```vb
context.Post(AddressOf SetForm1BitcoinPriceLabelText, "Test to see if I can edit the label")
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you a lot, I already "wasted" 10 hours on this so I am very happy to have it finally working. Still trying to find out how it works though:D

Comment: @BWS, read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387) for some background. It shows how to ensure code is executed on the UI thread in a form. There's also a later post on doing the same in a WPF window. The `SynchroniizatiionContext` class actually creates a WinForms or WPF control internally and uses that to do the same in a class that doesn't have direct access to a control itself. The `Send` and `Post` methods actually call `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` on that internal control.

Comment: @BWS, if an answer has resolved your issue, please accept it by clicking the check/tick mark next to it. That tells everyone that you don't need further help without their having to open the question and read your comment to find out.